# C# word document

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

I want to read a word document without opening it. Then replace some text in it and then save it with another name in the same format using C#. But the document is not being saved with the changes but int the same way as the original document. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/CustomerDocument/SampleNDA5.docx");
    WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, false);
    {
        var body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

        foreach (var text in body.Descendants<Text>())
        {
            if (text.Text.Contains("<var_Date>")) 
            {
                text.Text = text.Text.Replace("<var_Date>", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd,yyyy"));
            }
        }
        wordprocessingDocument.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/CustomerDocument/SampleNDA10.docx"));
        wordprocessingDocument.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help. It explains how to put edits back into a collection.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87616/List-T-ForEach-or-Foreach-It-Doesn-t-Matter-Or-Doe

Comment: While links in answers are great, you should explain the context and quote the relevant parts from the link that apply to the question (links may go stale or be dead at a later date, so the main content of the answer should be here).

Answer (score 1):

So if your word template is the same each time you essentially

- Copy The Template
- Work On The Template
- Save In Desired Format
- Delete Template Copy

Each of the sections that you are replacing within your word document you have to insert a bookmark for that location (easiest way to input text in an area).

I always create a function to accomplish this, and I end up passing in the path - as well as all of the text to replace my in-document bookmarks. The function call can get long sometimes, but it works for me.

```
Application app = new Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Open("sDocumentCopyPath.docx");

if (doc.Bookmarks.Exists("bookmark_1"))
{
    object oBookMark = "bookmark_1";
    doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMark).Range.Text =
            "My Text To Replace bookmark_1";
}
if (doc.Bookmarks.Exists("bookmark_2"))
{
    object oBookMark = "bookmark_2";
    doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMark).Range.Text =
            "My Text To Replace bookmark_2";
}

doc.ExportAsFixedFormat("myNewPdf.pdf", WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);

((_Document)doc).Close();
((_Application)app).Quit();
```

This code should get you up and running unless you want to pass in all the values into a function.

If you need some more explanation I can help as well :) my example saves it as a .pdf, but you can do any format you prefer.